# simple examples of MathGL/GLUT data plots

Tags: c++, glut

I'm looking for some simple examples on usage of GLUT or MathGL to plot datasets from C++.

I have looked through the documentation of MathGL and a bit through GLUT, but both require a drawing function to which no arguments can be passed.

I'm trying to visualize a simulation(1-3D) and want to have the plotting-routines separate from the simulation steps.
As I see it now I would have to pack the simulation steps in the draw() function (for MathGL and GLUT) - which I do not want.

Does anybody have any good pointers. I'd not be averse to another library if it's easy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you simply access your simulation data from `draw()` or `display()` ? Make it accessible by a `datatype GetDataMethod();` in you simulation class and you're done, aren't you?

Comment: I do not have the simulation set up in classes. For this kind it would be an overhead to start creating new classes.

Comment: This means your data is more or less global? If so, it is even easier I guess. Unless you don't tell more about your particular setup (code examples, etc.) it is hard to help you. I still think it shouldn't be a problem to simply access your data - in whatever way - from the `display()` function.